# What is the association bonus?

Tags: support, reputation

I just got 100  rep added to all of my Stack Exchange sites. Does anyone know why this happened? What does it mean?

Is it common? Does everyone get it? I am not sure.

(P.S. I know that this isn't exactly a Puzzling question, but it's puzzling me.)

Comment: Once you reach a certain reputation on one site, the stackexchange network counts as "trusted" and then adds 100 association bonus to any other site of the network you join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in.
>
> <sub>-From [the Help Center](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)</sub>

Comment: Alright thanks man